# Hide a gridView row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a `gridView` that allows adding new rows by adding the controls necessary for the insert into the `FooterTemplate`, but when the `ObjectDataSource` has no records, I add a dummy row as the `FooterTemplate` is only displayed when there is data.

How can I hide this dummy row? I have tried setting `e.row.visible = false` on `RowDataBound` but the row is still visible.

Answer (score 4):

You could handle the gridview's databound event and hide the dummy row. (Don't forget to assign the event property in the aspx code):

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 1)
            GridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following

```
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: This hid my entire GV.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="headertext">
            <ItemTemplate>
                itemtext
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                insert controls
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and the codebehind:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
    }
}
```

But I do not understand why you are adding your "insert controls" to the footer instead of placing them below the grid.

Answer (score 0):

This is the incorrect usage of the GridView control. The GridView control has a special InsertRow which is where your controls should go.

Comment: I always want the footer shown as that is where my insert controls are contained, I want to hide the DummyRow I add.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
e.Row.Height = Unit.Pixel(0);
```

This isnt the right answer but it might work in the meantime until you get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use CSS to set display none?!

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a special property to access Footer Row, named "FooterRow"

Then, you cold try yourGrid.FooterRow.Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

I did this on a previous job, but since you can add rows, I always had it visible in the footer row.  To make it so that the grid shows up, I bound an empty row of the type that is normally bound

```
dim row as Datarow = table.NewRow()
table.AddRow(row)
gridView.DataSource = table
gridView.Databind()
```

then it has all the columns and then you need.  You can access the footer by pulling this:

```
'this will get the footer no matter how many rows there are in the grid.

Dim footer as Control = gridView.Controls(0).Controls(gridView.Controls(0).Controls.Count -1)
```

then to access any of the controls in the footer you would go and do a:

```
Dim cntl as Control = footer.FindControl(<Insert Control Name Here>)
```

I'd assume you'd be able to do a:

```
footer.Visible = false
```

to make the footer row invisible.

I hope this helps!

*Edit* I just figured out what you said.  I basically delete the row when I add a new one, but to do this you need to check to see if there are any other rows, and if there are, check to see if there are values in it.

To delete the dummy row do something like this:

```
If mTable.Rows.Count = 1 AndAlso mTable.Rows(0)(<first column to check for null value>) Is DBNull.Value AndAlso mTable.Rows(0)(<second column>) Is DBNull.Value AndAlso mTable.Rows(0)(<thrid column>) Is DBNull.Value Then  
mTable.Rows.Remove(mTable.Rows(0))  
End If
mTable.Rows.Add(row)
gridView.Datasource = mTable
gridView.Databind()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it visible, just use:

```
Gridview.Rows.Item(i).Attributes.Add("style", "display:block")
```

And to make it invisible

```
Gridview.Rows.Item(i).Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the EmptyDataTemplate?  It seems to work great even though I have only been using it for a couple days...

Answer (score 0):

You should use DataKeyNames in your GridView:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FooID">`

And then retrieve it on your code:
`GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString()`

Where "0" is the number of the row you want to get the "FooID"

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to display data when the column/row is null:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataName))
{
    e.Row.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

It can easily be done by SQL

```
USE YourdatabaseName select * from TableName where Column_Name <> ''
```

Comment: -1 The question has nothing to do with SQL, he is trying to work with a GridView.