# How can I hide rows in Telerik's GridView?

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have a WPF `GridView`, and part of the data needs to be shown in the Totals (both Footer and Group totals), but not in the actual data records.

I thought it would be easy to write a trigger and hide the row based on  the row's data, however it turns out that Telerik's `GridView` uses an unusual panel for virtualization, so although the specified rows get hidden, a blank white space is left where it should go.

Here's my current style. It does hide the row, but it is the equivalent to making the visibility `Hidden` instead of `Collapsed` (hides the item, but leaves white space where it is)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewGroupRow}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Group.Key, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="SomeValue">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have tried setting the ItemTemplate to null, removing the Item from the Telerik's GridViewVirtualizingPanel, and adjusting the Visibility, but none of these options seem to work.

Does anyone know of a way I could accomplish this? I either want to hide (and collapse) the rows based on a trigger, or find a way to get the query of the current Grouped Expression so I can query a 2nd collection and display the results in the Group Total. I have no problem with using Code-Behind or something hackish to accomplish this.

**Edit**

As an interesting side note, I can set the height to 1, but not 0. Even 1 is too much though, since I can be hiding thousands of records and this leaves a huge white area on the screen.

Comment: You could use Snoop to find out which control you really need to collapse.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I tried that it and didn't help me. The Rows (item that is collapsed) are added to a custom `GridViewVirtualizingPanel`, which is Telerik's custom control that is displaying whitespace for collapsed Row items.

Comment: I had the same issue, and what I did is created another new property with only getter and on getter of it returning main lists values filtered with condition what I have

Comment: And binding the GridView itemsSource to new created property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted [a question on Telerik's forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/how-can-i-hide-a-row-in-the-gridview.aspx) as well, and apparently this is not possible. My options are to either filter the result set, or set the Height of the rows to 1.

If I filter the result set, my Aggregates are incorrect. If I set the row height to 1, I still get large areas of whitespace if there are a lot of records hidden (which there are).

My end solution was to set the row height of grouped row to 1, and just show non-grouped items. This means all items show if the data is ungrouped, but when grouped there is a 1px white line which is barely noticeable running through the grid where the hidden items are.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do this in the C#, here's code to auto hide a row in the databind:

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
   {
       GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
       if (item.GetDataKeyValue("EmployeeID").ToString() == "4")  //set your condition for hiding the row
       {
           item.Display = false;  //hide the row
       }
   }
 }
```

Most Telerik controls respond to a pattern like:

```
GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
editedItem.Display = false;
```

You can also do Columns:

```
GridColumn column = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("CustomerID");
if(column != null)
{
column.Visible = !column.Visible;
RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
```

Here's a similar question/answer:
[Hide a gridView row in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114521/hide-asp-net-gridview-row)

Comment: Where do you hook up that event? The RadGridView for WPF does not have an `ItemDataBound` event

Comment: Saw your edit... I am looking for a solution for Telerik's WPF GridView, not their ASP.Net GridView

Answer (score 1):

Make new boolean property in your binding collection 
bool: Visible{ge;set;}

Place in gridview and done.

```
​<telerik:RadGridView.FilterDescriptors>
 <data:CompositeFilterDescriptor LogicalOperator="Or">
 <data:CompositeFilterDescriptor.FilterDescriptors>
 <data:FilterDescriptor Member="Visible" Operator="IsEqualTo" Value="True" />
 </data:CompositeFilterDescriptor.FilterDescriptors>
 </data:CompositeFilterDescriptor>
 </telerik:RadGridView.FilterDescriptors>
```

Comment: As I said in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8344300/302677), filtering the result set makes the aggregate totals incorrect, so this was not an option for me.