# Hiding GridView columns in asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I have a gridview I am populating it by creating a datatable filling that table from my database connection then binding the data to my grid. I am not using the autogenerate columns but I am using autogenerate select. Searching through SO I found this suggestion.

```
    gridview.Columns[index].Visible=false;
```

when I added this line I get an index out of range exception thrown when i click the button in my web application.

I used that line after I bound my DataTable to the GridView but I want to hide a row to be used for a different purpose so I need to keep that information from my stored proc.

I also tried manually adding the columns with the `<columns>` option but it just adds the columns on top of the existing ones.

I am a little new to web programming and taking out the autogenerate select is an option but doesn't help me as much as I would have to spend a lot of time learning to recode the select row feature of the table i dont have. Everything I have read so far has dealt with the autogenerate column problem but I am not using it and if the autogenerate select causes the same issue. I might have no choice.

Comment: It's still noch clear what actually your *issue* is.

Comment: sorry about that i didnt add that i was getting index out of range error. i changed my question to reflect that. i basically need to be able to hide a row in a gridview. if its still unclear i will try to post some of my code.

Comment: Before you're going to edit your question, what does _hide a row_ mean, should it be rendered to the client with `display:none` or not at all(`Visible=false`)? Do you need to access controls in it on clientside or not? Note that you can always access controls and their values on serverside even when they are invisible. You should also show your button-click handler where you're trying to hide that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding a row requires binding to the OnRowDataBound event and setting the style.

Check out this answer: [Hide a gridView row in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114521/hide-asp-net-gridview-row)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem I did not realize that AutoGenerateColumns was by default set to true. Whether it is by default or because i used AutogenerateSelect control I am not completely sure but my fix was to explicitly set the AutogenerateColumns to False then populate the grid from the columns element in the control. Thank mello for your reply you got me to the answer i needed.